# System tick timer interrupt priority and blocked interrupts

Tags: timer, operating-system, interrupt

Assume we have an OS that is running on a CPU which is fully compatible with its requirements. This OS is tick driven. System tick interrupt arrive from external timer (periodic mode) which is connected to some CPU IRQn pin for simplicity.

IRQ pins are sorted by interrupt priority. IRQ0 has the highest priority and IRQn has the lowest priority. Priority is there at least for two reasons. First one is of course when arrive two interrupts together, one with higher priority is selected. The second reason is following: when interrupt occurs, further interrupts are disabled by hardware. When interrupts are in ISR enabled (possible nesting interrupts), only interrupts with higher priority can occurs. And I have some questions about it.

My first question is probably really simple and I can answer it by myself (maybe), but I want to read reliable answer.

- **How to choose timer tick priority? Is it the lowest interrupt priority in the system?***

Here is the second question.

- **What if timer tick interrupt occurs exactly while CPU is serving another interrupt(s) and further interrupts are disabled?**

And here is addition by me. If can happen the above situation (in the second question), there is a chance to lost system tick. Can it cause any big problems?

*If timer tick priority wasn't the lowest interrupt priority in the system, it may occurs situation when CPU is in ISR with lower priority than system tick interrupt and enables further interrupts and user process, that we need for potentially scheduling, is stored somewhere on the stack, where we can't find it in system tick routine.

I know that it all can be system-dependent, but I am interested in any typical solutions that are similary to this situation.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Well, typically, a timer tick interrupt is used to time out those syscalls that ask for a timeout, eg. I/O read calls and inter-thread synchro waits.  In those cases where an I/O/whatever completion occurs 'at the same time' as a timeout, it would seem reasonable to give the completion interrupt a higher priority than the timeout, ie. it's just sneaked in under the wire:)    I suspect that there's not much in it, however, overall performance-wise.

Comment: I mean, why bother worrying?  If the tick interrupt gets deferred until a higher-priority interrupt has completed, it may, or may not, find that the timeout that it was set up to fire has disappeared from its queue/whatever - OK, so it does nothing except interrupt-return.  If the timer interrupts a lower-priority interrupt that is about to signal a completion of a call with a  timeout, then yes, the system must be designed to signal that the call has failed, both to the call originator thread and the interrupted ISR.  Fun, isn't it:)

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose it, but I am still a little worried about my thoughts.

Comment: "This OS is tick driven" First of all, you should try to be a bit more precise on that point. What exactly is the purpose of the tick? Is it to provide global system time? For scheduling? *What* is driven by that tick? When you know that you're able to assign a suitable priority to the tick, depending on the importance of the OS function driven by it.

Comment: @DanielJour Thank you, too.

Comment: Here is another question: We have HW-wired timer, which is used for system timer interrupt, with the highest priority. How is solved this situation? How timer routine knows that registers can belongs to interrupt routine (which enables nested interrupts) or a process?